# Can anyone please tell me how to integrate Jasper Report with Struts2 and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2, jasper-reports

I've created a web application using struts2 and hibernate framework.
In my application i planned to use jasper report for reporting, which i used commonly in desktop application for reporting.
In desktop application calling a jasper report is quiet very easy.But in the same way in web application with struts2 and hibernate framework i don't know how to call a jasper report in jsp.
can anyone please tell me how to integrate jasper report in web apps that use struts2 and hibernate framework

here is my source code what i've done so far

**Sample.jasper** which resides in a default folder with struts.xml and hibernate.conf.xml (its all working in preview mode)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a309cf26-d77c-4e85-8d52-2a89cff70117">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="43"/>
    <queryString language="hql">
        <![CDATA[FROM Login]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="pass" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5eaebc5a-8cc1-45dd-9596-c4057ea97aed" x="118" y="41" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5eaebc5a-8cc1-45dd-9596-c4057ea97aed" x="271" y="41" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="07e4ccc0-6491-4a87-b03b-bed972fb344d" x="118" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="07e4ccc0-6491-4a87-b03b-bed972fb344d" x="271" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pass}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**struts.xml** (i don't know how to call the jasper from action)

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    </package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [**Struts2 JasperReport Tutorial**](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.8/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html) (next time, *before* asking a question ;)

Then, your package should extend `jasperreports-default` (the specific Interceptor Stack created for working with JasperReports), not `struts-default`:

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="jasperreports-default">
```

and your Action should return a [Jasper result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.8/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html):

```
<result name="success" type="jasper">
    <param name="location">/jasper/our_compiled_template.jasper</param>
    <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
    <param name="format">PDF</param>
</result>
```

Also ensure that you have a recent Struts2 version, most of the options are `Struts2 2.1.2+` compatibles...